# Unable to apply bevel to circular edge

Tags: edges, bevel

I'm able to select the circular edge here with alt+click, however, when I try to bevel this edge, nothing happens:

[image]

I've tried cleaning up the mesh with merge by distance, and verified every edge in the circle is selected before beveling, but no joy..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have asked Higgins... :D

1. select all vertices
2. press M -> merge by distance
3. select loop
4. CTRL-B -> bevel -> move mouse for more cuts

[image]

Comment: Awesome, exactly right.. Thanks 

Comment: you are welcome